# Is possible to render any page which user want but to load some local style like style='color:white;?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have WebView control on my page and I need to change default font settings like color and font. Is possible to render any page which user want but to load some local style like style='color:white; ? Where to put css and how to load css ?